# May i populate object prop in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My current scheme

```
const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
     ...
})
```

Now i need to add ACL (role) to each user. And ACL should be saved near user, but not inside it, because the same user may have different ACL's in different deps.

So i plan to use this scheme like this:

```
marketingDepartment: { 
    usersWithAcl: [
        { user:xxxxx, ACL: 'admin' },
        { user:yyyyy, ACL: 'employee' },
    ]}
```

I want to use something like `find({}).populate('usersWithAcl.user')` and then get whole user object in `user` prop.

Is it possible to do in mongoose?
If yes, how should i construct my schema to implement it?

Is there better solution to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can populate from object property.

like:

```
const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    usersWithAcl: [{
     user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
     ACL: String
    },_id: false],//added _id: false to avoid generate mongoose id in usersWithAcl
    //.......
})
mongoose.model('Department', departmentSchema);
```

and find with populate

```
Department.find({}).populate('usersWithAcl.user')
```